# C# how can we get the text between quotes in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string sample: `" 'john', 'michile,k', 'dana's font' "` .

How can i get the output like below:

```
'john'
'michile,k'
'dana's font'
```

Note: I have a provision to change the 'dana's font' some thing like 'dana\'s font'...

Comment: Where should that be outputted ?

Comment: Get a **real** csv parser from NuGet, and suddenly this will be trivial with less code, fewer potential unaddressed edge case issues, and better performance.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)?

Comment: @David Won't work because of the extra comma in the michile,k text. It's really best to avoid string.split for all but the most simplistic or constrained data sets.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: That depends.  Splitting on the comma-space combination can work, at least for the limited sample data shown.  Though I certainly agree that the OP should better understand the source and format of this data to more effectively work with it.

Comment: As long as commas and an unescaped quoting character is allowed in the string there is no failsafe solution. Its broken by design. We can only get a solution that works for this example string.

Comment: Things you shouldn't do when programming: rolling your own cryptographic function, parsing HTML with regex, and thinking you've covered all the edge cases in a CSV.

Comment: It is not hard to provide a solution to this particular input but things may well get more complicated. The format of the input must be *well defined*; they may include escape characters, for example. Otherwise the situation will be similar to fighting in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split by `', '` and then add the `'` back for 1st and last word.

```
var text = " 'john', 'michile,k', 'dana's font' ";
var list=text.Split("', '");

Console.WriteLine(list[0] + "\'");
for (int i=1 ; i<list.Length-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\'"+list[i]+ "\'");
}
Console.WriteLine("\'" + list[list.Length-1]);
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: Use the Textbox tools `{}` button to code format and you can use two spaces for newlines instead of html br's.